# How can we display hidden paragraph when we click on a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

```
<div class="inf-frame-text">
<h4> Learning Plus </h4>
<p> For our clients, the future is a continuum. It’s not about the next big thing, it's simply everything that's next. The next experience. The next innovation. For our clients, the future is a continuum. It’s not about the next big thing, it's simply everything that's next. The next experience. The next innovation. For our clients, the future is a continuum. It’s not about the next big thing, it's simply everything that's next. The next experience. The next innovation.  </p>
<a class="inf-read-btn"> Read More + </a>
</div>

        .inf-frame-text {
            margin-top: 120px;
            &:first-child {
                margin-top: 0;
            }
            p {
                height: 62px;
                overflow: hidden;
                transition:height 0.3s ease-out;
            }
            p.is-active {
                height: 100%;
                overflow: visible;
                transition:height 0.3s ease-out;
            }
        .inf-read-btn {
            display: block;
            color:#00ffbf !important; 
            cursor: pointer;
        }

      $('.inf-read-btn').on('click', function() {
        $('.inf-frame-text p').toggleClass('is-active');
      });
```

Hey guys I need to create few grids with contents. But few parts of the contents should be hided and when I click on that read more button it should show all contents with toggle animation. Here I just tried some java script code for that but didn't work well. Also one more thing is when click on that button all the other contents should be hided except the contents related to that button we going to click.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you did not close the `.inf-frame-text` style correctly. It is missing a closing brace.

```
.inf-frame-text {
   margin-top: 120px;

   &:first-child {
      margin-top: 0;
   }
```

```js
$('.inf-read-btn').on('click', function() {
  // Find the container whose button was clicked
  var $container = $(this).closest('.inf-frame-text');
  // find the p inside it
  var $elem = $container.find('p');
  
  // toggle the p element for that container
  $elem.toggleClass('is-active');
  
  $('.inf-frame-text p').not($elem).removeClass('is-active');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.inf-frame-text {
  margin-top: 120px;
  &:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}

p {
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}

p.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
  overflow: visible;
}

.inf-read-btn {
  display: block;
  color: #00ffbf !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inf-frame-text">
    <h4> Learning Plus </h4>
    <p> For our clients, the future is a continuum. It’s not about the next big thing, it's simply everything that's next. The next experience. The next innovation. For our clients, the future is a continuum. It’s not about the next big thing, it's simply
      everything that's next. The next experience. The next innovation. For our clients, the future is a continuum. It’s not about the next big thing, it's simply everything that's next. The next experience. The next innovation. </p>
    <a class="inf-read-btn"> Read More + </a>
  </div>
  <div class="inf-frame-text">
    <h4> Learning Plus </h4>
    <p> For our clients, the future is a continuum. It’s not about the next big thing, it's simply everything that's next. The next experience. The next innovation. For our clients, the future is a continuum. It’s not about the next big thing, it's simply
      everything</p>
    <a class="inf-read-btn"> Read More + </a>
  </div>
  <div class="inf-frame-text">
    <h4> Learning Plus </h4>
    <p> For our clients, the future is a continuum. It’s not about the next big thing, it's simply everything that's next. The next experience. The next in it's simply everything that's next. The next experience. The next innovation. </p>
    <a class="inf-read-btn"> Read More + </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No..actually i need java script code for that. This section needs some behavior, I have added those above. Can you please help me?

Comment: Check the updated post. You can play around with opacity instead.

Comment: Or you can set the `height: 0; overflow: hidden;` to achieve the same.

Comment: When we click on button using my codes all the contents will show and hide. I need one grid content open when click on a readmore button and others should hide. And when click on other readmore button that should be open and the old one should close automatically...

Comment: Thank you so much buddy...:)) Im trying to put height and instead of opacity...:)

Comment: Glad it worked out for ya. Once you feel this solves the problem, mark it as an answer so that it helps others :)

Comment: Sure...I'll do that:))

Comment: Bro..can we give animation to that content? I tried transition but i didn't work..is there any solution??